# Problem in GeneXus SD, when update a level of transaction

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

I have faced a problem on GeneXus SD. I want to update the level of the transaction on GeneXus mobile. I pass the parameter as **Attribute Primary key** and **Attribute level primary key** for update level. Level attribute gets the value when **ClientStart** but not shown the value in the table from the SD panel.

For example,

Transaction Design:

[image]

Work With For Smart Device (Details - City):

[image]

After Clicking **Update** button on the view screen then update the city, Work With For Smart Device (Update - City):

[image]

```
Event 'Update'
    WorkWithDevicesCountry.City.Detail.Update(CountryId, CountryCityId)
Endevent
```

Update value not shown on the panel and can't update the process. Attached a video for reference smart device screen specially update portion. Link: https://youtube.com/shorts/2EhSSpzziYQ?feature=share

Also added an attachment XPZ example: https://shorturl.at/glz17

Version: GeneXus17U8

I maintain all documentation which is available on the GeneXus wiki. I guess, It's a problem on the genexus side. I am stuck there in our current running project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The multi-level transactions have some restrictions when the Work With (mobile) pattern is applied to them.
> The recommendation is to use one-level transactions for each level and apply the pattern for each one.
> It is not necessary to remove the original two-level transaction, you can create parallel transactions (with the same key) and apply the pattern to them.

Here is the response received from Genexus support which may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Connectivity Support to Online, instead of Inherit.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).